# Stubbing a prisma client method with sinon

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon, prisma

I am trying to write unit tests for a class that should save a task with a prisma client.

```
export class TaskHandler {
  ...
  public async save(ctx: PrismaClient, input: TaskInput): Promise<Task> {
    if (input.label == null || input.number == null) {
      throw new Error('Input not complete');
    }
    return ctx.task.create({
      data: {
        label: input.label,
        number: input.number,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

For my unit tests i am using sinon to stub the relevant parts. So my current unit test looks like this:

```
import { stub } from 'sinon';
...
describe('Tasks', () => {
  const prismaClient = new PrismaClient();
  describe('Task handler', () => {
    it('should save a item', async () => {
      const instance = new TaskHandler();
      const task: TaskInput = {
        label: 'test',
        number: 12,
      };
      const resultTask: Task = {
        id: '1',
        label: 'test',
        number: 12,
      };
      const stubInstance = stub(prismaClient.task, 'create').resolves(
        resultTask,
      );
      const result = await instance.save(prismaClient, task);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      stubInstance.reset();
    });
  });
});
```

Now when i call save on my task handler, after i called stub on the create function of the prismaClient.task, Prisma is still validating my database schema, so i asume that the original create function is still getting called instaed of just returning the result that i expect the stub would return.
What am i missing here?

Comment: Where does `PrismaClient` come from? Provide the code

Comment: Do you plan to mock the PrismaClient? Did you had a look at this guide?
https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing#mocking-the-prisma-client

Comment: I had a look at this guide, but since i am working with sinon id doesn't really help me much. And yes i do want to mock the Client, or prefarably only stub specific functions